# 'return false' doesn't return from function

Tags: c++, network-programming

А am implementing tcp-connection C++ wrapper for ARM-based robot running under Linux.
Here is my code:

```
bool tcp_connection::wait_connection(int port)
{
  is_server = true;

  if (!create_socket())
    return false;

  local_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  const int result = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
  if (result < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "tcp_connection.cpp: Error on binding '" << strerror(errno) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "return false" << std::endl;
    return false;
    std::cout << "after return false???" << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "listening...." << std::endl;
  .....
  return true;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
tcp_connection.cpp: Error on binding 'Address already in use'
return false
listening....
```

How it could happen?

Comment: Is it possible the function is being called twice, and `result>=0` the second time?

Comment: It is returning for sure, it is why there is no "after return false?" line. But the "listening..." must come from another call to the function, check the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning. If it wasn't, your output would be:

```
tcp_connection.cpp: Error on binding 'Address already in use'
return false
after return false???
listening....
```

It's likely that the `listening...` print is from a subsequent call to `wait_connection()` where the `if (result < 0)` branch is not taken.

Comment: You are right. It succeeded on the second loop.
I'm sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's a legitimate question and you did your best to narrow it down.